# Unstable voltage reading at mobile battery terminals

Tags: battery-charging

I just observed a weird thing. My mobile battery got swollen and I purchased a new one. Before putting new battery into the phone, I plugged the charger and measured the voltage at mobile terminals (the three terminals where we connect the battery) with a Digital multimeter and the voltage was quickly and randomly varying from 0 to 4. Should not it be stable around 4.3v? I think that damaged my previous battery. Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: The battery is already damaged, and if the reading you are taking is the output voltage (and not the digital communications line), then the fluctuating voltage means that the battery's built-in protection has triggered and is cutting the battery out. The charger will be applying the charge periodically. The "charger" you plugged **is not a charger**! It's a USB power supply. The charger is built into the phone itself. You can't remove it without destroying the phone :)

Comment: `I think that damaged my previous battery.` ... why do you believe that?

Comment: Sounds like the "charger" which is actually a 5V supply, is trying to start up, but the battery takes a huge current at 4V and trips its overcurrent protection. ("Charger" waits a second and tries again, same result). Don't do that; charge the new battery IN THE PHONE.

Comment: I think my question has been misunderstood. I got fluctuating readings without a battery connected to the phone. I removed the battery, plugged the 5v supply, and then measured the output voltage at mobile terminals. @jsotola I have a UPS and it charges a 12v battery at constant 12v output. I think phones should do the same.

Comment: `I think phones should do the same` ... if the phones have a lead-acid battery, then yes